# Kotlin - Trying to populate spinner from Fragment using findViewById(), but context: this is throwing an error

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-spinner

Obligatory preface: I'm quite new to Kotlin and Android Studio. As the title states, I'm trying to populate a spinner in Android Studio from within a fragment. First, I had an issue with `findViewById(R.id.spinner)` but I believe I've resolved it by prefixing it with `root.`.

Currently, the only error being thrown is the `context: this` line. Ultimately, I'd like to use this spinner to allow the user to filter by different NY boroughs (hence, `boroughs_array`. Here's my current code within the FilterFragment -- my attempt to populate the spinner begins below `return root`.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?


): View? {
    filtersViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FiltersViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filters, container, false)
    return root

    val spinner: Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.spinner)
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        R.array.boroughs_array,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    ).also { adapter ->
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.adapter = adapter
    }
```

My current assumption is that `this` is not the right context, as I'm within a fragment. On the off-chance that this is correct, I'm not really sure how to handle this. **If you can shine any sort of light on the issue, I will be eternally grateful.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use use `context!!` instead of `this`. `this` refers to the current `Fragment`, which is not a `Context`. The current `Fragment` has a reference to the `Context` though, accessed via `this.getContext()`, or `context` for short.

The reason you need `context!!` is because `getContext()` is `nullable` (it may return `null`). It's safe in this case to 'force unwrap' (`!!`) because `context` will never be `null` inside `onCreateView()`.

Another issue I've spotted, is you're returning from the `onCreateView()` function before you've set up the spinner.

Try this instead:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?


): View? {
    filtersViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FiltersViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filters, container, false)

    val spinner: Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.spinner)
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        context!!,
        R.array.boroughs_array,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    ).also { adapter ->
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.adapter = adapter

    return root
}
```

Also, just for further clarification - you've probably seen some examples where `this` is passed in for `context`. This is often done inside of an `Activity`, since `Activity` does extend `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `context` like this:

```
context?.let { context ->
   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        context,
        R.array.boroughs_array,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
    ).also { adapter ->
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```