# Kotlin problem with Spinner inside Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner, android-spinner

I have a problem with the spinner inside a fragment. The spinner is filled with data, but when I select an item I don't see logs, and in the spinner, it does not select elements. When I used nearly the same code as an activity it worked (Just changed the context to this in the adapter)

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_stoper, container, false)
        val tagSpinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.editSpinner)
        val items: MutableList<String> = ArrayList("a","b","c")
        tagSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this.requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items) as SpinnerAdapter
        tagSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = this

        return view
    }
 override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        Log.d(TAG,"OnItemSelected: $type")
    }
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        Log.d(TAG,"error")
    }
}
```

Comment: possible answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401980/kotlin-trying-to-populate-spinner-from-fragment-using-findviewbyid-but-cont

Answer (score 1):

Is your fragment really a listener for spinner?
Write a custom listener and use that instead of your fragment.

```
    inner class SpinnerStateChangeListener : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        // do sth here
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        // do sth here
    }
}
```

Now you can set your listener like this:

```
tagSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = SpinnerStateChangeListener()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your implementation from Fragment directly to spinner. remove override from class and instead of

```
tagSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
```

do

```
tagSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object :AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
                Log.d(TAG,"error")
            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Log.d(TAG,"OnItemSelected: $type")
            }

        }
```

Comment: I already tried it and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add *requireActivity().applicationContext* in the adapter to change the activityFragment to a context:

```java
...
 val items: MutableList<String> = ArrayList("a","b","c")
 tagSpinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity().applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items) as SpinnerAdapter
tagSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
...
```